# Constrained optimization given in google code jam

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint-programming

Any library that can solve this constrained optimization problem in google code jam? Especially if more constraints are added which break the given solutions. Or at least how are such problems termed in theory?

Round 1A 2013
Problem B. Manage your Energy

https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2418487/dashboard#s=p1

Comment: Constrained optimization problems are usually solved with [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), but this sounds like a dynamic programming problem. I'm not sure if you'd be able to solve the larger test cases with just linear programming. EDIT: Actually, I think a greedy solution might be sufficient...

Comment: this is probably mixed integer linear programming problem